# Java: Detecting image format, resize (scale) and save as JPEG

Tags: java, image, resize, javax.imageio, graphics2d

This is the code I have, it actually works, not perfectly but it does, the problem is that the resized thumbnails are not pasting on the white Drawn rectangle, breaking the images aspect ratio, here is the code, could someone suggest me a fix for it, please?

Thank you

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class ImageScalerImageIoImpl implements ImageScaler {

 private static final String OUTPUT_FORMAT_ID = "jpeg";

 // Re-scaling image
 public byte[] scaleImage(byte[] originalImage, int targetWidth,
   int targetHeight) {

  try {
   InputStream imageStream = new BufferedInputStream(
     new ByteArrayInputStream(originalImage));
   Image image = (Image) ImageIO.read(imageStream);

   int thumbWidth = targetWidth;
   int thumbHeight = targetHeight;

   // Make sure the aspect ratio is maintained, so the image is not skewed
         double thumbRatio = (double)thumbWidth / (double)thumbHeight;
         int imageWidth = image.getWidth(null);
         int imageHeight = image.getHeight(null);
         double imageRatio = (double)imageWidth / (double)imageHeight;
         if (thumbRatio < imageRatio) {
           thumbHeight = (int)(thumbWidth / imageRatio);
         } else {
           thumbWidth = (int)(thumbHeight * imageRatio);
         }

   // Draw the scaled image
   BufferedImage thumbImage = new BufferedImage(thumbWidth,
     thumbHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   System.out.println("Thumb width Buffered: " + thumbWidth + " || Thumb height Buffered: " + thumbHeight);

   Graphics2D graphics2D = thumbImage.createGraphics();
   // Use of BILNEAR filtering to enable smooth scaling
   graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
     RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
   // graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null);

   // White Background
   graphics2D.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
   graphics2D.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, targetWidth,
     targetHeight));
   graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);

   System.out.println("Target width: " + targetWidth + " || Target height: " + targetHeight);

   // insert the resized thumbnail between X and Y of the image 
   graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null);

   System.out.println("Thumb width: " + thumbWidth + " || Thumb height: " + thumbHeight);

   // Write the scaled image to the outputstream
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ImageIO.write(thumbImage, OUTPUT_FORMAT_ID, out);
   return out.toByteArray();

  } catch (IOException ioe) {
   throw new ImageResizingException(ioe);
  }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily scale your image by using [`Image`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)'s [`getScaledInstance`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int)) method:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
int scaleX = (int) (img.getWidth() * 0.5);
int scaleY = (int) (img.getHeight() * 0.5);

Image newImg = img.getScaledInstance(scaleX, scaleY, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

Once you've obtained your scaled `Image` you can "convert" it back into a [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) as described [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt.image/Image2Buf.html).

Finally, use the [`ImageIO`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class to write your `BufferedImage` to a file.

Comment: The scaling needs to be dynamic depending of the target Canvas container. Anyway, Ive solved it my self with a good refactoring and a couple of logic fixes. Thank you anyway

Comment: link does not work. hints for Image to BufferedImage transformation?

Comment: Which link doesn't work?  I just tried them all and they seem ok.

Comment: FYI: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt.image/Image2Buf.html redirects to parked domain sites.

Comment: getScaledInstance may not be your best friend: https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html