# How do I resize a .jpg image file on my Android device right before upload?

Tags: java, android, android-image, android-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [resize image from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420802/resize-image-from-file)

I have a `File f` and it's a .jpg. I want to resize it to 640x480 right before I upload it to my PHP web service. I want it to maintain correct ratio (no stretching/skewing).

What's the quickest and easiest way to do this?

Comment: This sounds very related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744909/java-detecting-image-format-resize-scale-and-save-as-jpeg

Comment: @Chris Android doesn't include AWT.

Comment: @kabuko - thanks - I was sure this was something I'd seen before and didn't know about the AWT thing.

Comment: It isn't possible to maintain the aspect ratio of all images while re-sizing them to a discrete WxH value like 640x480. You would have to have to do some cropping.

Comment: @SemperFLy If you want to maintain aspect then you cannot enforce HxW w/o cropping or stretching unless your image already had required aspect ratio